# Labelling feynman diagrams in tikz-feynman package

Tags: feynman, tikz-feynman

Consider the following piece of code using the tikz-feynman package.

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]
    \begin{feynman}
        \diagram [vertical'=a to b] {
            {   [edges={draw=none}]
                a -- b [label=0:\(\mu_{3}\)]
                -- c [label=-180:\(\mu_{4}\)]
                -- d [label=-180:\(\mu_{1}\)]
                -- a [label=0:\(\mu_{2}\)],
            },
            {   [edges={photon}]
                a -- ap [particle=\(p_{2}\)],
                b -- bp [particle=\(p_{3}\)],
                d -- dp [particle=\(p_{1}\)],
                c -- cp [particle=\(p_{4}\)],
            },
        };
        \diagram* {
            (c) -- [fermion] (b)
                -- [fermion] (d)
                -- [fermion] (a)
                -- (c),
        };
    \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %
    \feynmandiagram[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}, vertical'=a to b,] {
        {   [edges={fermion}]
            a -- [edge label=\(k+p_{1}+p_{2}\)] b [label=0:\(\mu_{3}\)]
            -- [edge label=\(k-p_{4}\)] c [label=-180:\(\mu_{4}\)]
            -- [edge label=\(k\)] d [label=-180:\(\mu_{1}\)]
            -- [edge label=\(k+p_{1}\)] a [label=0:\(\mu_{2}\)],
        },
        {   [edges={photon}]
            a -- ap [particle=\(p_{2}\)],
            b -- bp [particle=\(p_{3}\)],
            d -- dp [particle=\(p_{1}\)],
            c -- cp [particle=\(p_{4}\)],
        },
    };
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]
    \begin{feynman}
        \diagram [vertical'=a to b] {
            {   [edges={draw=none}]
                a -- b [label=0:\(\mu_{3}\)]
                -- c [label=-180:\(\mu_{4}\)]
                -- d [label=-180:\(\mu_{1}\)]
                -- a [label=0:\(\mu_{2}\)],
            },
            {   [edges={photon}]
                a -- ap [particle=\(p_{2}\)],
                b -- bp [particle=\(p_{3}\)],
                d -- dp [particle=\(p_{1}\)],
                c -- cp [particle=\(p_{4}\)],
            },
        };
        \diagram* {
            (a) -- [anti fermion] (b)
                -- [anti fermion] (d)
                -- [anti fermion] (c)
                -- (a),
        };
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

It gives me the following output:

[image]

I would like to add a caption to each of these diagrams with the words 'Figure I,' 'Figure II' and 'Figure III' respectively.

How do I do so?

Comment: Just have a look how to do that with normal pictures, using \begin{figure} and \caption{} and so on. Or maybe I do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please make your code complete with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. If I add only `\usepackage{tikz-feynman}` I get a strange result. If your problem is the roman number for the figures, just add `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Roman{figure}}` and use `\begin{figure}...\caption{...}\end{figure}` for every `tikzpicture`.